# Determine value of $M - m$

Tags: sequences-and-series, maxima-minima

Let $$a_n = \frac{\sin(n \pi/2)}{2^n}$$ 
Where $a_n$ is a sequence of numbers . If $M = \max{a_n}$ and $m = \min{a_n}$ then what is the value of $M- m$ ?

**My try** : I found the convergence point using squeeze theorem but I'm unable to using it for computing maximum and minimum .

**Edit** : The previous sequence was wrong .

Comment: How about considering $$\Im\left({\sum_{r=0}^n\dfrac{e^{in}}{2^n}}\right) = \Im\left(\sum_{r=0}^n\left(\dfrac{e^{in}}2\right)^n\right)=\ldots$$

Comment: @Kevin Can you explain more ? I'm not familiar with that .

Comment: Minimum is attained for $n=0$ so that  $m=a_0=0$ 

Maximum is when $n=1$ and $M=a_1=\dfrac{1}{2} \,\sin \frac{1}{2}$

$M-m=\dfrac{1}{2}\, \sin \frac{1}{2}$

Comment: @Raffaele $a_3\approx -0.12219126470813713192364187681233$ is smaller than your "minimum".

Comment: @ProfessorVector You are right, thank you! Minimum is $a_3=\frac{1}{8} \sin \frac{9}{2}$  Thus $M-m=\frac{1}{2}\sin \frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{8} \sin \frac{9}{2}\approx 0.362$

Answer (score 1):

We have $|a_n|\leq\frac{1}{2^n}$, hence both $M=\max_{n\in\mathbb{N}}a_n$ and $m=\min_{n\in\mathbb{N}}a_n$ are attained pretty soon.
 By direct inspection, $m=a_3$ and $M=a_1$.

Comment: Sorry , after asking my friend I understood the right sequence is $a_n = \frac{\sin(n \pi/2)}{2^n}$ . Can you help me now ?